# Dumping and gzipping MySQL db (with Python subprocess) sometimes results in corrupted file

Tags: python, mysql, amazon-s3, subprocess, gzip

I would like to create automated backups of a MySQL db. My desired behavior is as follows

1. `Cron` job runs once per day
2. dump file is zipped and archived to `Amazon S3`

When I need to restore from a backup, the following happens..

1. connect to Amazon S3
2. download the zipped dump file from the appropriate bucket
3. unzip the file and reinstate the db from that file.

**What is happening:** Everything seemed to be working great. I have all of the behavior automated using Python. I have made successful backups and successfully restored the database just as expected.

Now I am noticing that sometimes the dump-zip-archive process is resulting in a dump file that cannot be restored. I am getting the error `gzip: myDumpFile.sql.gz: unexpected end of file` when I try to re-instate the db. I have noticed that usually an unsuccessful backup file will be smaller in size than one that works ok (good: 2 Mb. bad: ~600 Kb). I do not get any errors while running the python script to create a corrupted backup.

**How I am doing it**

I am using the `boto` Python library to communicate with `Amazon S3`. The actual dump file gets created as below

```
import subprocess
...
dump_cmd = ['mysqldump ' +
            '--user={mysql_user} '.format(mysql_user=cfg.DB_USER) +
            '--password={db_pw} '.format(db_pw=cfg.DB_PW) +
            '--host={db_host} '.format(db_host=cfg.DB_HOST) +
            '{db_name} '.format(db_name=cfg.DB_NAME) +
            '| ' +
            'gzip ' +
            '> ' +
            '{filepath}'.format(filepath=self.filename)]
subprocess.Popen(dump_cmd, shell=True)
...
```

When I want to restore, the file is downloaded from S3 and the following command is issued

```
unzip_cmd = ['gzip -d {filename}'.format(filename=self.filename)]
restore_cmd = ['mysql ' +
               '--user={mysql_user} '.format(mysql_user=cfg.DB_USER) +
               '--password={db_pw} '.format(db_pw=cfg.DB_PW) +
               '--host={db_host} '.format(db_host=cfg.DB_HOST) +
               '{db_name} '.format(db_name=cfg.DB_NAME) +
               '< ' +
               '{filepath}'.format(filepath=self.filename[:-3])]
subprocess.Popen(unzip_cmd, shell=True)
subprocess.Popen(restore_cmd, shell=True)
```

Why does this sometimes result in a corrupted `.gz` file? There is no correlation between when `CRON` runs it or I manually execute, good and bad dumps have come from either.

**Note** I have been warned against using `shell=True` as a security hole, although in this case it is safe as only I have access to the server and am responsible for the config file and inputs.

Comment: @BK435 I am taking the dump off of a live database with active connections

Comment: @BK435 I have not watched the CRON run, but I have run it manually. Running manually fails randomly

Comment: `Popen()` returns immediately. Have you tried `check_call()` instead?

Comment: @BK435 that is dangerous advice... you *cannot* safely copy the data directory of a running MySQL Server as a method of backup.  That is not supported.  You are also incorrect on your speculation about connection counts or timeouts.  Both of those conditions would result in an **error free gzip container** with a truncated or empty file of SQL statements within it.  The error clearly indicates the gzip structure is corrupt, and conveys no information about the payload.

Answer (score 1):

According to J.F Sebastian's comment to my original question, I have come to learn that `subprocess.Popen()` returns immediately.

My program was initiating the database dump, and then immediately moving to the function that does all the upload work. So, an incomplete database dump was being sent to `AWS S3`. Solution was adding the `.wait()` function.

```
dc = subprocess.Popen(dump_cmd, shell=True)
dc.wait()
```

User `BK435` had suggested to take a copy of the running database data file as an alternative, but that comment has since been negated / removed. In it, he mentioned that taking the mysqldump off of a running database was not a good idea, but I have not found evidence to support that this is a bad idea. It does lock tables, but I am ok with the app going down for a few minutes each night.

Comment: 1. note: `check_call()` calls `.wait()` for you. Look at [its implementation](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/b65c586bcedf8f2afb996d1d45ca8d4a26e146c2/Lib/subprocess.py#L552-l582). 2. It is probably ok to use `mysqldump` if it locks the tables but it is not ok to copy bare db files (e.g., using `cp`, `rsync`).